# What is the difference between view and view_as in PyTorch?

Tags: pytorch

I am building neural networks in Pytorch, I see `view` and `view_as` used interchangeably in various implementation what is the difference between them?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`view` and `view_as` are very similar with a slight difference. In `view()` the shape of the desired output tensor is to be passed in as the parameter, whereas in `view_as()` a tensor whose shape is to be mimicked is passed.

`tensor.view_as(other)` is equivalent to `tensor.view(other.size())`

Comment: something I never understood is the difference between `view` and `reshaping` (as in numpy). Do you know what the difference is?

Comment: Should the size/shape of tensor & other be same?
For ex: a = torch.arange(1,17) & b = torch.arange(101,110).
Does this work?: a.view_as(b)

Comment: @AvidLearner the number of elements in each tensor should be the same to use `view_as()`.